# Assign column name for the rowname in R table

Tags: r

if i have a list of numbers that indicate age: 3,5,6,7
and a have a list of names corrspond to the age above: allen, jack, amy,alex
if i want to creat a table that contain only 1 column the age,i want it should looks like this as it call in the console

```
Names Ages
allen 3
jack  5
amy   6
alex  7
```

i used the following code

```
>table<-matrix(age_list, nrow = 4, ncol= 1, byrow = TRUE)
>rownames(table)<- name_list
```

and i only can assign 1 column name as

```
>colnames(table)<-c("Ages")
```

but the result is like following

```
      Ages
allen 3
jack  5
amy   6
alex  7
```

How can assign the "Names" in upper left corner of the table with only contain 1 column in such a table. Thanks

Comment: Avoid the use of `table` for naming, as it is also a built-in function.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using a matrix, then the answer is you can't assign the upper left hand corner.  The row names of an R matrix are not part of the matrix data itself.

However, you can use a data frame instead:

```
table <- data.frame(Names=c("allen", "jack", "amy", "alex"),
                    Ages=c(3, 5, 6, 7))

> names(table)
[1] "Names" "Ages"
```

Comment: `R matrices do not have row names` do you mean that the rownames don't have a column name?

Comment: actually, i used as.table to convert it to table type which is the type i must have. i tried to do it in dataframe and convert it to table, when i call it, it always display a column of row numbers from 1 to 4 at the left. do you have any solution to solve it? or can you tell me how to eliminate that numer column in the left as it is still a table type. thanks

Comment: The code in your original question is not very reproducible, so it's hard to give you an exact answer, because we are not sure exactly what you want.  If you want the `names` column to be a part of your data, then it should exist as actual column in a data frame or matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like:

```
ages <- c(3,5,6,7)
nams <- c("allen","jack","amy","alex")

out <- matrix(ages)
dimnames(out) <- list(Names=nams, "Ages")

#Names   Ages
#  allen    3
#  jack     5
#  amy      6
#  alex     7
```

Comment: Thanks you guys,. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You could try,

```
names(dimnames(table)) <- c("Name", "Age")

#        Age
#Name    [,1]
#allen    3
#jack     5
#amy      6
#alex     7
```